# Facebook App: Make the landing page redirect to a URL?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to make the landing page (what I understand by landing page: the page the user first sees when they view the FB app or the page they get redirected to after they accepted an invitation to the app, right?) redirect to some URL of my choosing? Like `mysite.com/User/Register`... would that work or does Facebook not allow that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure the landing page to be whatever you want it to be. But if that's not an option (maybe you want to track it as a hit to that page or something) you can always redirect whenever you want using `top.location.href` in an iFrame app, or `<fb:redirect url="" />` in FBML.