# How do you configure a Facebook app to send the user directly to the website?

Tags: facebook

Notice how clicking on the Instagram App entry of a facebook search sends the user *directly* to instagram's website. **How is this accomplished?**

There appears to be a somewhat related question (with an accepted answer) here: [Facebook App: Make the landing page redirect to a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6037782/1196206) However, it isn't clear this is the correct way to do it, as it doesn't provide the same user experience.

Invoking such an implementation will *first* send the user to what would be a facebook app page with an iframe. Then that iframe (with the suggested redirect code) invokes the redirect. This is quick, but still obvious to the user, and clearly different. Not to mention, it may also go against Facebook's terms (not sure though).

**Bottom line is, how does one configure a facebook app link to behave as the Instagram app link?**

(Note, I would have simply added this comment to the referenced question, but it seems I don't have the required rep points yet).

Answer (score 3):

in the https://developers.facebook.com/apps - go to "edit app", and in the Settings -> Basic, choose only "Website with Facebook Login" (and you'll see a green V).

Now go to "App Center" in the left bar - fill all the necessary forms and hit submit.
and then go to: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/YOUR_APP_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but here is my two cents;

Go to the App Developer page on Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
Create a new application and on Settings -> Basic enter your website URL under Website (after you clicked on it)
Then goto Settings -> Advanced and at the bottom of the page there is an button which says Create Facebook Page click on it and once someone clicks on your Facebook page they should be redirected to your website.

Comment: that doesn't work, as this just sets up a facebook page. No redirection occurs.

Comment: Have you tried? Once I did something similar and it worked. But then I created one throught the website tools.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. My question is how to get the App link to be redirected, not the Page link (but neither are redirected in fact).

Comment: Facebook "suggested" a JavaScript approach like this <script>top.location.href='url';</script> It might just work :)